# Mask Array with boolean Comparison to Smaller dimension Array Python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, mask

first time asking a question and I'm also really bad at coding. I have a 2D array shape=(100,4000) and want to manipulate all values in each row that are greater than the corresponding value in an 1D array shape=(100,).

I want to do this in the most efficient way as it will soon be an array with shape=(1000,8000) potentially. Not sure how to broadcast in a boolean mask or if I even can? Below is an example of my code that is obviously not working. I could do what I want by using a for loop or by duplicating the LX array to be the shape=(100,4000) but I want it to be faster than these options.

```
dX = np.random.rand(100,4000)
LX = np.random.rand(100)
LX2 = LX/2
dX[dX>LX2] = dX[dX>LX2]-LX[dX>LX2]
```

Comment: You can compare a 2D array with another 2D array. `LX` and `LX/2` are 1D arrays. To add a dimension, you can do `LX = LX[:, None]`

Comment: However, `dX > LX2` is a `(100, 4000)` shape array. You can't use such an array to mask a `(100, 1)` shape array.